# Cancelling piping files with request module throw ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js

I'm doing a simple request with express & the [request](https://github.com/request/request) module and piping its response to `res`:

```
var pipe = request.get({
    url: 'url-to-file'
});

pipe.on('response', function (response) {

    req.on('close', function () {
        // these methods won't work:
        // pipe.unpipe();
        // pipe.end();
        // pipe.finish();
        // pipe.close();
    });

    pipe.on('end', function () {
        // this will never fire if I cancel the request
    });

    res.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers);

    pipe.pipe(res);

});
```

This works like a charm, except if I cancel downloads. The end event won't fire and some seconds later, an ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error gets thrown.

How can I close the pipe? [These node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_unpipe_destination) claim that I can call `.unpipe`, but all node gives is `pipe.unpipe` is not a funtion (tested with v0.12.7 & 4.2.2 & & 5.0.0), probably because it's not an original node stream.
I also tried using events like end, finish and close, but neither of them work.

Comment: Have you tried `pipe.destroy()` within the `close` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request.get()` does not return a pure node.js stream but rather a `Request` object which inherits from the native `Stream` class and adds some custom methods. The method you are looking for is `Request#abort()` ([Source link](https://github.com/request/request/blob/cb5b7ac919545c13c03c3e7f00ee2737527d8139/request.js#L1039)).

Your code example would look like the following:

```
var pipe = request.get({
    url: 'url-to-file'
});

pipe.on('response', function (response) {

    req.on('close', function () {
        pipe.abort();
    });

    pipe.on('end', function () {
        // this will never fire if I cancel the request
    });

    res.writeHead(response.statusCode, response.headers);

    pipe.pipe(res);

});
```